# Why is my apply pandas function turning every value into a None value?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update the values in a dataframe column. There are three different values in this column, which I will call **Alive**:

`Alive`
`-`
And NaN values.

So I wrote a function to change the values:

```
def update_vals(x):
    if x == "-":
        x = False
    if x == "NaN":
        x = np.nan
    else:
        x = True

ppl_dataframe['Alive'].apply(update_vals)
```

However, when I go to apply this function, it simply results in None values being applied across the entire column.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you have `NaN` as a string or the values are actual np,nan  values?

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].**

Answer (score 2):

your function doesn't have a `return` statement so by default it returns `None`, you could use:

```
def update_vals(x):
    if x == "-":
        return False
    if x == "NaN":  # if you have np.nan values you have to change with np.isnan(x)
        return np.nan
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `apply`, `np.select`

```
import numpy as np 


s1=ppl_dataframe['Alive']=='-'
s2=ppl_dataframe['Alive']=='NaN'

np.select([s1,s2],[False, np.nan],default=True)
```